# Draw Rhombus in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

When we want to crop a section from an image what we normally use is cvSetImageROI() method and pass a rectangle as a parameter. In my case, I want to crop a rhombus from an image so that I have to pass a rhombus as the parameter. So I need to know how to draw a rhombus in opencv. Can someone help me with this problem. Thank You !

Comment: How will drawing a rhombus help you "crop a rhombus"?

Answer (score 0):

No special function available, use a [`polyline`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines)